# How to change the Credit Card Number of Recurring Payment Transaction?

Tags: php, paypal

I have implemented the Recurring payment transaction on my site,
 Now my client wants an interface to change the Credit Card Number of that recurring transaction, by submitting only Payment ID(found from `CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile`). So my question is, is there any API (php) to `update an credit card number` of recurring payment transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ACCT variable in [UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile_API_Operation_NVP/)

Comment: Thanks @Preston Alexander for reply... I just want to know one thing more that, is that the other parameters must be same as the parameters which i set on the time of `CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile`...  and one more thing that, can i change the date of next transaction also?

Comment: I don't think other parameters are required, you only need update what you want to update.  I'm not sure about changing the date-- I believe so, but try it in sandbox and see.

Comment: Thanks @Preston Alexander It works perfectly...
Actually You have to pass only `credit card details` and `profile_id` Thats it. I hope i will get the answer for changing date also(still working on it).

Answer (score 1):

This is the exact Code which worked for me...

```
$URPDetails = new UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestDetailsType();
    $UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestTypeObj = new UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestType();
    $UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestTypeObj->UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestDetails=$URPDetails;

    $UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfileReqObj = new UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfileReq();
    $UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfileReqObj->UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequest=$UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestTypeObj;
    $paypalService = new PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService();

        try {
            /* wrap API method calls on the service object with a try catch */
            $createRPProfileResponse = $paypalService->UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile($UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfileReqObj);   
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            echo 'ERROR: '.$e->getMessage()."\n";
            //exit;
        }
```

where `$URPDetails` object contains the `Credit Card Details` and `ProfileId`